# Is there anyway I can call the year once?

Tags: php, posts, loop, query-posts, blog-page

Hi everyone I hope you have a great day, I was wondering if is there anyway I can call the year once?. I really don't know if its possible to call the date once cause mine keeps on repeating calling the year for every each post I have and here's the picture below what the output should look like

[image]

and here's a copy of my code

```
<div class="common_wrapper">
    <?php
                    
        if(have_posts() ): while(have_posts () ): the_post();?>

        <div class="wrapper_100">
        
            <div class="width_30">
                <h2><?php the_time('Y') ?></h2>
            </div>

            <div class="width_70">
                <a href="<?php echo get_permalink(); ?>">
                    <div class="wrapper">
                        <div class="width_50">
                            <?php the_time('Y.m.d') ?>
                        </div>
                        <div class="width_50">
                            <?php the_title();?>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </a>
            </div>

        </div>

    <?php endwhile; ?>
                
    <?php else: endif;?>
</div>
```

Thank in advance and stay safe

Comment: Don't just spit out the time like that. Simply add some logic to check if you're dealing with a new year, and if so, output that year in the first div. If not, don't.

Comment: Hi sir I'm really sorry for asking this could you give me a hint or code with conditions on how to call the year once?, thank you